# Person didn't pay yet took the app and put it online

Tags: difficult-client, late-payment

So I made an app for this person and he did give me 50% of the money. But the thing is he just gave me 50% of the money and put the app on the play store. Now whenever I try to contact him he says he is busy or in hospital or something. I stopped all his ad services but still isn't replying. Is there any way I can remove his app from the play store.

Comment: Could you please explain the timeline a little bit better? That is, from your description, it seems like you delivered an app to him, and after the delivery, he paid you 50% of what you two agreed to. Is that correct?

Comment: He transferred 50% before hand and said he would give the final payment after I give him the apk but after that he jusy makes some excuses,

Comment: How does your contract handle late/non-payments? That could be legally enforceable if you take him to a small claims court.

Answer (score 3):

@user3772366, was the 50% that he paid you an initial milestone payment? If you've tried talking to him already and it doesn't work, perhaps it's time to shoot an email to the Google Developers Support team and tell them your situation and tell you them you have the original source code to prove that the app was developed by you.

This has happened to another developer that I know of and it was resolved when Google took the app offline while they wait for the guy that posted the app online to respond to the conflict.

I think it's definitely worth a shot. I seriously hope you have the payment arrangement in paper trial (emails, letters, etc) so that you can prove that he has not fulfill his side of the bargain.

FYI, perhaps watch this before you start any new job ;) [F@%# You, Pay Me](http://creativemornings.com/talks/mike-monteiro--2/1)

Comment: Can you please guide me through the process? I am fairly new to all this.

Comment: Try this. I just did a quick Google search since my friend is not online on Skype atm for me to ask.

Write to Google using this link (in Market console "Help" on the upper side, then "Contacting Us" on bottom and then
"Android Market Developers: Publishers & Merchants" then
probably "Application Removal" which would lead you to this:

http://www.google.com/support/androidmarket/bin/request.py?contact_type=publisher

If he hasn't paid you for the app in full, then in effect he is stealing your app and you should be able to request a C&D from Google.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably screwed.

Don't do this again.  When final payment is due, DEMONSTRATE the app via Skype, but don't send a thing to the client until you've received ALL your money.

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot. Did you give him the sources? I hope not.

You can give his app negative comment and you can rate the client badly via the website you used to work thru.

You said you have access to his add service? That is good cause you control his money inflow.

But other that what you already did, there is not anything you can do.

Comment: He has recourse depending on his country.  In any country with strong contact law and/or strong copyright law he likely has legal recourse.  The contract should have stated that IP (copyright etc.) will not be transferred in the case of non-payment, then the app can be removed via a copyright violation claim.

Comment: Leaving a negative comment means bad publicity for the freelancer.  I wouldn't recommend that.